# Pyspark: how to create aggregation of time based values when aggregation window is a variable

Tags: python, pyspark, time-series, aggregation

I have a dataframe as below where I have values measured in interval of 5 minutes. I want to aggregate these values over a larger interval, lets say 15, 20, 30 or 60 minutes, that I wish to pass as an interval of aggregation. The aggregation interval can be assumed to be in range X - 60 where X >= interval_length <= 60 and a factor of 60 (such as 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30) for simplicity.

```
TIMESTAMP_COL               interval_length     value
2019-08-03T07:05:00.000Z    5                   5.34
2019-08-03T07:10:00.000Z    5                   4.5
2019-08-03T07:15:00.000Z    5                   4.74
2019-08-03T08:20:00.000Z    5                   5.64
2019-08-03T08:25:00.000Z    5                   4.5
2019-08-03T08:30:00.000Z    5                   4.56
2019-08-03T08:35:00.000Z    5                   4.56
2019-08-03T09:40:00.000Z    5                   4.56
2019-08-03T09:45:00.000Z    5                   4.68
```

I have tried below for 15 minute interval and works

```
    df = df.withColumn('time_utc_flat',
                             F.when(F.col("interval_length") < 15,
                                    F.when(((F.minute(F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) > 0) &
                                           (F.minute(F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) <= 15)),
                                           F.date_trunc('hour', F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) +
                                           F.expr('INTERVAL 15 MINUTES'))
                                     .when(((F.minute(F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) > 15) &
                                           (F.minute(F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) <= 30)),
                                           F.date_trunc('hour', F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) +
                                           F.expr('INTERVAL 30 MINUTES'))
                                     .when(((F.minute(F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) > 30) &
                                           (F.minute(F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) <= 45)),
                                           F.date_trunc('hour', F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) +
                                           F.expr('INTERVAL 45 MINUTES'))
                                     .when(((F.minute(F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) > 45) &
                                           (F.minute(F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) <= 59) &
                                           (F.second(F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) <= 59)),
                                           F.date_trunc('hour', F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)) +
                                           F.expr('INTERVAL 60 MINUTES'))
                                     .otherwise(F.date_trunc('hour', F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL))))
                              .otherwise(F.col(TIMESTAMP_COL)))
```

and then I can apply aggregation as below:

```
    df_agg = df \
    .groupBy("time_utc_flat") \
    .agg(F.sum(value).alias("value")) \
    .withColumnRenamed("time_utc_flat", TIMESTAMP_COL)
```

but I want the logic to be dynamic so that I can pass the aggregation_interval as a function parameter such as:

```
def agg_input(df, agg_freq):
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code

Parse the strings in `TIMESTAMP_COL` to timestamp type

```
freq = 15
df = df.withColumn('utc_ts', F.to_timestamp('TIMESTAMP_COL'))

# df.show()
# +--------------------+---------------+-----+-------------------+
# |       TIMESTAMP_COL|interval_length|value|             utc_ts|
# +--------------------+---------------+-----+-------------------+
# |2019-08-03T07:05:...|              5| 5.34|2019-08-03 12:35:00|
# |2019-08-03T07:10:...|              5|  4.5|2019-08-03 12:40:00|
# |2019-08-03T07:15:...|              5| 4.74|2019-08-03 12:45:00|
# |2019-08-03T08:20:...|              5| 5.64|2019-08-03 13:50:00|
# |2019-08-03T08:25:...|              5|  4.5|2019-08-03 13:55:00|
# |2019-08-03T08:30:...|              5| 4.56|2019-08-03 14:00:00|
# |2019-08-03T08:35:...|              5| 4.56|2019-08-03 14:05:00|
# |2019-08-03T09:40:...|              5| 4.56|2019-08-03 15:10:00|
# |2019-08-03T09:45:...|              5| 4.68|2019-08-03 15:15:00|
# +--------------------+---------------+-----+-------------------+
```

Truncate the timestamp to hour. Divide minutes by the desired frequency thne floor the result of division. Now add the resulting minutes to truncated timestamp to create bins of desired frequency

```
exp1 = F.expr(f"date_trunc('hour', utc_ts)")
exp2 = F.expr(f"make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {freq} * floor(minute(utc_ts) / {freq}), 0)")
df = df.withColumn('utc_ts_binned', exp1 + exp2)

# df.show()
# +--------------------+---------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
# |       TIMESTAMP_COL|interval_length|value|             utc_ts|      utc_ts_binned|
# +--------------------+---------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
# |2019-08-03T07:05:...|              5| 5.34|2019-08-03 12:35:00|2019-08-03 12:30:00|
# |2019-08-03T07:10:...|              5|  4.5|2019-08-03 12:40:00|2019-08-03 12:30:00|
# |2019-08-03T07:15:...|              5| 4.74|2019-08-03 12:45:00|2019-08-03 12:45:00|
# |2019-08-03T08:20:...|              5| 5.64|2019-08-03 13:50:00|2019-08-03 13:45:00|
# |2019-08-03T08:25:...|              5|  4.5|2019-08-03 13:55:00|2019-08-03 13:45:00|
# |2019-08-03T08:30:...|              5| 4.56|2019-08-03 14:00:00|2019-08-03 14:00:00|
# |2019-08-03T08:35:...|              5| 4.56|2019-08-03 14:05:00|2019-08-03 14:00:00|
# |2019-08-03T09:40:...|              5| 4.56|2019-08-03 15:10:00|2019-08-03 15:00:00|
# |2019-08-03T09:45:...|              5| 4.68|2019-08-03 15:15:00|2019-08-03 15:15:00|
# +--------------------+---------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Group the dataframe by binned timestamp and aggregate value with some

```
df_agg = df.groupBy('utc_ts_binned').agg(F.sum('value').alias('value'))

# df_agg.show()
# +-------------------+-----+
# |      utc_ts_binned|value|
# +-------------------+-----+
# |2019-08-03 12:30:00| 9.84|
# |2019-08-03 12:45:00| 4.74|
# |2019-08-03 13:45:00|10.14|
# |2019-08-03 14:00:00| 9.12|
# |2019-08-03 15:15:00| 4.68|
# |2019-08-03 15:00:00| 4.56|
# +-------------------+-----+
```